# How to do content based dynamic routing in zuul?

Tags: spring-boot, routes, microservices, netflix-zuul

I am working on a micro-services based architecture which includes Spring-Boot, Eureka, Zuul at key level. My problem is as follows:

Service1 : /api/v1/service1 POST

Service2 : /api/v2/service2 POST

application.yml looks like

```
zuul:
    routes:
        service1:
            path: /api/v1/**
        service2:
            path: /api/v1/**
        common:
            path: /common/endpoint
```

Also I have written a filter where I am trying to take input via this common endpoint and deduct based on post request where to enroute the request i.e. to service1 or service2. But here I am stuck and nothing seems to work out, even after several google searches and checking out other people's problem I am not yet able to found my solution.
here is how my Filter looks like:

```
public class CommonEndpointFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        if ((ctx.get("proxy") != null) && ctx.get("proxy").equals("common")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

        InputStream in = (InputStream) ctx.get("requestEntity");
        if (in == null) {
            try {
                in = request.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String body = null;
        try {
            body = StreamUtils.copyToString(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

            if (body.indexOf("somethingrelatedtoservice1") != -1) {
                //forward the request to Service1: /api/v1/service1
            } else if (body.indexOf("somethingrelatedtoservice2") != -1) {
                //forward the request to Service2: /api/v1/service2
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return FilterConstants.ROUTE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to forward the request further to those services and then obtain response to send back via common endpoint.

What am I doing wrong here ? How can I proceed so I don't have to use hardcoded url of any of the service. Please guide me through this.

I have tried out some of the things like:

1. using DiscoveryClient to obtain instance and use setRouteHost method of context. It always throws a zuulfilter exception URL is not proper common/endpoint is appended after the url of service obtained via DiscoveryClient.
2. I tried stupidest thing that came to mind, using RestTemplate to make a request and obtain response and put that in context response which didn't work either, however request was forwarded to the service but I wouldn't receive any response.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What URL is your client trying to call?  I think you are making this more difficult than it needs to be.  Does your client know if its calling service 1 or service 2?

Comment: it appends the endpoint at the end even though I don't use it, for example if DiscoveryClient makes the url http://something.com/api/v1/service1 then the called url is http://something.com/api/v1/service1/common/endpoint which makes no sense.

Comment: Have you checked this article https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/

Comment: @ankurkushwaha it did appear in the search results but it is very basic which I already know, it doesn't provide any information which could solve my problem.